# Is there a way to get all column names in a table for IBM Netezza?

Tags: sql, netezza, aginity

I'm using aginity workbench and netezza at my workplace.

Is it possible to run a query to get all columns for the tables stored here?

Thanks

Comment: can you run the query that i wrote

Comment: Hey mate, i got an error that "as"is expecting a keyword